# Can expo app receive push notification with image on iOS?

Tags: ios, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Expo App (SDK 48) receiving push notifications.

On android I receive them with the sent image, but iOS doesn't receive the image. This is an Expo limitation or there's an iOS extra step to receive images?

I'm sending them through firebase admin sdk following this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image). I have tried through firebase console as well and the result is the same:

> Android receives the notification with image but iOS receives it without image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! I had to do some expo prebuild configurations following [rn firebase docs](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/ios-notification-images)